# Passenger with apache and nginx on the same development box

Tags: apache, nginx, passenger

I've got Apache and passenger on my notebook. I want to test Nginx and passenger on the same machine. I can install Nginx on 8080 and apache on 80. But can I install passenger with both the same server on the same machine?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, simply install the apache module and then the nginx module. You'll probably need to make sure each server has a different `PassengerTempDir` setting too.

Answer (score 0):

I had both Apache and Nginx with passenger installed and working fine on the same Arch Linux machine, serving a Rails app. Once, with apache running and listening on port 80, I started nginx listening on the same port and got an (expected) error about the port being already bound. I stopped apache and nginx, restarted nginx and started getting Bad Gateway errors whenever I tried to access the Rails app under Nginx. I still haven't figured out what the problems is and how to fix it. Rebooting doesn't seem to help.